# I changed hosts file but can't see effects

Tags: windows, wordpress, hosts

I have to reach the wordpress platform installed by a certain hosting service, so I can build a new website (that will replace the old one), on a certain IP address. I changed my hosts file under their instructions. I put in it the IP address that they had given me and the website domain (separated by a single space). The hosts file hasn't any extension and it's in the right location (System32/drivers/etc - I'm on Windows 8). I cleaned browser and local DNS cache but nothing change: if I put in the browser the url they had given me (www.domain.com/?hostingname) I see the old website, not the wordpress platform. I tried to ping the domain and it returns a different IP address. What can I do? Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Did you open the file as an administrator?  If you don't you cannot save the changes.

Comment: I think this is more server related maybe ask in serverfault

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved. It's important to edit the hosts file with Windows Notepad and not with Notepad++